# Twitter Bootstrap popovers disappearing too quick

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap popovers to create a "Quick View" effect to display more information when people mouse over an item. The content of the popover comes from an Ajax call.

The code below works fine on the very first hover; however, on subsequent mouseovers, the popover disappears too quickly and doesn't let you view the content.

Can anybody figure out what the issue could be?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Quick view boxes
    var overPopup = false;

    $("a[rel=popover]", '.favorites').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function(){
            var div_id =  "div-id-" + $.now();
            return details_in_popup(div_id, $(this).data('product-id'));
        }

    }).mouseover(function (e) {
        // when hovering over an element which has a popover, hide
        // them all except the current one being hovered upon
        $('[rel=popover]').not('#' + $(this).data('unique')).popover('hide');
        var $popover = $(this);
        $popover.popover('show');

        $popover.data('popover').tip().mouseenter(function () {
            overPopup = true;
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            overPopup = false;
            $popover.popover('hide');
        });

    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        // on mouse out of button, close the related popover
        // in 200 milliseconds if you're not hovering over the popover
        var $popover = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!overPopup) {
                 $popover.popover('hide');
            }
        }, 200);
    });
});

function details_in_popup(div_id, product_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/get_product_ajax',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#' + div_id).html(json['success']);
            }

        }
    });
    return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `.not('#' + $(this).data('unique'))` to `.not('[data-unique="' + $(this).data('unique') + '"]')` fixes the problem.

I'm not exactly sure why this problem exists, but I know the problem also disappears if you remove "bootstrap-transition.js" from the equation.

Comment: Thank you very much, This fixed the issue. Is it also possible to do the ajax call just once? Right now, the ajax call is made every time I mouse over an item. Is it possible to tweak the js so if the div already has content, don't try to populate it any more.

Comment: @farjam Yes, it's possible. I suggest you post another question for that. I'm on my phone at the moment, but I think you should be able to get an answer pretty quickly if you give your question the "jquery" tag.

Comment: Added [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961207/jquery-making-an-ajax-call-to-be-requested-only-once). Thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to find an answer to my other question yet. Do you mind taking a look at the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961207/jquery-making-an-ajax-call-to-be-requested-only-once) and let me know if you have any input on that too. Appreciate your help.