# jQuery: Making an Ajax call to be requested only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code to display a "popover" effect on my products. The content of the popover comes from Ajax. This is using [Twitter Bootstrap popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). Is it possible to make the Ajax call only once? Right now, every time I mouse over the product, the request is sent again. I'd like to tweak this code so if the content has already been fetched, use it and don't make another request.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Quick view boxes
    var overPopup = false;

    $("a[rel=popover]", '.favorites').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function(){
            var div_id =  "div-id-" + $.now();
            return details_in_popup(div_id, $(this).data('product-id'));
        }

    }).mouseover(function (e) {
        // when hovering over an element which has a popover, hide
        // them all except the current one being hovered upon
        $('[rel=popover]').not('[data-unique="' + $(this).data('unique') + '"]').popover('hide');
        var $popover = $(this);
        $popover.popover('show');

        $popover.data('popover').tip().mouseenter(function () {
            overPopup = true;
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            overPopup = false;
            $popover.popover('hide');
        });

    }).mouseout(function (e) {
        // on mouse out of button, close the related popover
        // in 200 milliseconds if you're not hovering over the popover
        var $popover = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!overPopup) {
                $popover.popover('hide');
            }
        }, 200);
    });
});

function details_in_popup(div_id, product_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/get_product_ajax',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#' + div_id).html(json['success']);
            }

        }
    });
    return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
}
```

Here is how my html structure looks like:

```
<div class="image">
    <a data-unique="unique-3" data-product-id="39" rel="popover" href="link to product">
        <img src="path to image" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone for your help and input. Here is how I fixed it:

```
function details_in_popup(div_id, product_id){

    //I added this block
    if ( $("#popover_content_for_prod_" + product_id).length ) {
        return $("#popover_content_for_prod_" + product_id).html();
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/get_product_ajax',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if (json['success']) {
                $('#' + div_id).html(json['success']);

                //Also added this line
                $('body').append('<div style="display:none;" id="popover_content_for_prod_' + product_id + '">' + json['success'] + '</div>');
            }

        }
    });

    return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden element to store the value of the `boolean` and get it before the AJAX call then set it when done.

HTML:

```
<div id="hiddenElement" value="true" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

JS:

```
var once = $("hiddenElement").val();

if (once) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php?action=add_driver", 
        dataType: "json",
        date:  $("form#addDriver").serializeArray(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.error, .success, .notice').remove();
        }
    }).done(function() {
        $("#hiddenElement").val("false");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just modify the ajax function to store the retrieved data on the element with `data()`, and check if there is any such data stored before you do the ajax call etc. sort of like a "caching" function :

```
function details_in_popup(div_id, product_id){
    var data = $('#' + div_id).data(product_id);
    if ( data ) {
        $('#' + div_id).html(data);
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=product/product/get_product_ajax',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){
                if (json['success']) {
                    $('#' + div_id).html(json['success'])
                                   .data(product_id, json['success']);
                }

            }
        });
        return '<div id="'+ div_id +'">Loading...</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @adeno Is your solution compatible with jquery 1.7.1? After I use your modified function, I get the error in jquery that "TypeError: a.split is not a function"

Comment: @farjam - it should be, just tested it with 1.7.2 without seeing any issues!

Comment: Can't get it to work unfortunately. And also keep in mind, looks like since that div-id is using the now() function to append a timestamp to itself, it's guaranteed to be unique, so your if statement would always go to the "else" route, hence repeating the request.

Comment: I see, then I guess you'll need to store something on each popover anchor to know wether or not the ajax has been done already. Concept is the same, you need to store something somewhere where you can check it later, and you need to store a different something on each element to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a global boolean variable `isFetched`.
Check for `isFetched` before Ajax request, and perform the request only if the `isFetched` is false.

```
var overPopup = false;
var isFetched = false;
var data = '';
$("a[rel=popover]", '.favorites').popover({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: function(){
        var div_id =  "div-id-" + $.now();
        if(!isFetched){
            data = details_in_popup(div_id, $(this).data('product-id'));
        }
        isFetched = true;
        return data;
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you give an example on how this would be used? I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Right below `var overPopup = false;`, add a line `var isFetched = false;`. And then change your return statement to: `return isFetched ? details_in_popup(div_id, $(this).data('product-id')) : false;` It should work this way

Comment: Oh I see. I was under impression that isFetched is a javascript function hence I wrote that comment. Sorry about that. :) I'll try this shortly and let you know how it works.

Comment: I added your lines, but right now no popover is produced at all (which makes sense, because isFetched is false initially). And shouldn't I set the isFetched to true at some point?

Comment: I just edited the main post, please try doing what I did there.

Comment: I think we're getting close. The Ajax request is only made once now; however, the second time I mouse over, I can only see the "Loading..." content appear, not the actual content.

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` before the return statement and check via console if the variable contains the web info or not.